# Javadoc like documentation for Citrus Framework

Tags: javadoc, citrus-framework, object-model

I am used to refer javadocs/object model for any new solution/framework I am learning. I tried to look for the same for Citrus Framework and I couldn't find it. Can someone please point me to that or something similar. I would like to understand all the classes/methods available in Citrus Framework. Thanks.

Comment: For example: Understanding TestContext component of Citrus Framework. I would like to understand all the methods supported by it. I guess I can look into the source code to understand it but I would prefer a javadoc documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to go with the [user guide](http://citrusframework.org/citrus/reference/html/index.html). It describes all important functionality from a users perspective and points out the important interfaces to be used to customize Citrus and extend it with your domain specific functionality.
Another good point to start from is the [samples repository provided on github](https://github.com/citrusframework/citrus-samples).
In addition, the javadoc can be found on [javadoc.io](http://javadoc.io/doc/com.consol.citrus/citrus-core/2.7.7).

Comment: Thanks for the javadoc Sven. I have just started with the Citrus Framework. Sure the user guide and the samples are helpful. The javadoc will help me to understand the overall architecture of the framework. 
Anyway my question is answered. This thread can be closed.

Comment: You're welcome! So please mark the question as answered. Thx.